# @JsonUnwrapped Not Working, Convert Flattened JSON into Custom POJO

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to populate a POJO from a JSON using Jackson. My sample request is-

```
    POST /lab2/person?firstname=John&lastname=Doe&email=john.doe@anony.com&street=190 South&city=Houston&state=TX&zip=12345 
    HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Person - POJO

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonUnwrapped;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String firstname;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String lastname;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String email;

private String description;

@Embedded
@JsonUnwrapped
private Address address;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
private Organization organization;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
/**
 * @return the firstname
 */
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
/**
 * @param firstname the firstname to set
 */
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
/**
 * @return the lastname
 */
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
/**
 * @param lastname the lastname to set
 */
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
/**
 * @return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
/**
 * @return the address
 */
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
/**
 * @param address the address to set
 */
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
/**
 * @return the organization
 */
public Organization getOrganization() {
    return organization;
}
/**
 * @param org the organization to set
 */
public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
    this.organization = organization;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{name : "+this.getFirstname()+" "+this.getLastname()+", email : "+this.getEmail()+", "+this.getAddress().toString()+", "+this.getOrganization().toString()+"}";
}
}
```

Controller Method is -

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute Person person){
    System.out.println("In person");

    System.out.println(person.getFirstname()+" "+person.getLastname()+" "+person.getEmail());
    System.out.println(person.getAddress().toString());
    return "Welcome";
}
```

When my code runs, I get the values of firstname,lastname and email while address being an object throws null pointer exception and does not get set.

Error -

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/lab2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cmpe275.lab2.controller.PersonController.addUser(PersonController.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    In person
    John Doe john.doe@anony.com
```

How can I get the address object values set. The Address POJO looks like -

```
   package com.cmpe275.lab2.model;

   import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

   @Embeddable
   public class Address {


private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
/**
 * @return the street
 */
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
/**
 * @param street the street to set
 */
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
/**
 * @return the city
 */
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
/**
 * @param city the city to set
 */
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
/**
 * @return the state
 */
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
/**
 * @param state the state to set
 */
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
/**
 * @return the zip
 */
public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}
/**
 * @param zip the zip to set
 */
public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "address : "+this.getStreet()+","+this.getCity()+","+this.getState()+", "+this.getZip();


};

}
```

I read various blogs but there is no generic solution available. I dont want to create a custom Mapper.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a version of your code with `Person` and `Address` and successfully serialized and deserialized a `Person` object. Therefore the problem is not with `@JsonUnwrapped` and the particular classes `Person` and `Address` classes. There are 2 potential causes that I can think of :

1. the JSON document you tried to deserialize is corrupt or incompatible with your POJO structure.
2. the version of Jackson you are using is obsolete and incompatible with the other dependencies. I can see `import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonUnwrapped;` in your code that's an old version of Jackson. Try a more recent version (e.g. 2.5.3) and do `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;`